# SonarQube ClassNotFound

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I've got following errors when running SonarQube 5.1.2 with nightly build job

```
[ERROR] [01:39:46.669] Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
[ERROR] [01:39:46.672] Class not found: javax.el.ELResolver
[ERROR] [01:39:46.673] Class not found: javax.el.ValueExpression
[ERROR] [01:39:46.674] Class not found: javax.el.ExpressionFactory
[ERROR] [01:39:46.674] Class not found: javax.el.ELException
[ERROR] [01:39:46.674] Class not found: javax.el.ELContextListener
[ERROR] [01:40:23.297] Class not found: javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream
[ERROR] [01:40:23.778] Class not found: javax.json.JsonObject
```

Can you please advise what is the best way to handle such an errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve these problems by adding

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: close but not enough: `<version>3.0.1-b04</version>` must also be added (before the scope tag)

Answer (score 1):

Those indicates that the java analyzer was not able to find the binary files (ie .`class` files) during analysis and as such was not able to totally complete the semantic analysis of some files of your project.

To make those errors go away, provide those classes to the analyzer using  `sonar.java.libraries` property.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think Sonar 5.1.2 will understand maven dependencies with **provided** scope? Or should I download jars from maven central by hands?